# Network accessible IP for each docker container

Tags: docker, networking

I would like to deploy multiple applications via docker. Some of them are using the same port. 
An alternative port mapping (Port 80->5080) is not an option, so my way to handle the problem is a network bridge which should allow me to assign an ip address from my internal network to each container.

The answer from this post does not work for me
[Assign LAN IP address to Docker container different from host's IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714891/assign-lan-ip-address-to-docker-container-different-from-hosts-ip-address)

i am able to assign an ip to the docker container, but it also gets the host ip address so i can not map ports.

Comment: Did you consider starting a reverse proxy such as Nginx?

Comment: Can i assign multiple ip addresses to my host and route it via Nginx to different ports?

Comment: The "standard docker solution" for this problem with an Nginx reverse proxy seems to require domaines. i just have an ip address