# Assigning static IP on the host network to container

Tags: docker, docker-network

I need to run a docker container (hosting nginx), such that the container gets a static IP address on the host network. Example:
Suppose the host has IP 172.18.0.2/16 then I would like to give 172.18.0.3/16 to the docker container running on the host. I'd like the other physical machines in the host's network to be able to connect to the container at 172.18.0.3/16.
I have tried the solution described by: https://qiita.com/kojiwell/items/f16757c1f0cc86ff225b, (without vegrant) but it didn't help. I'm not sure about the `--subnet` option that needed to be supplied to the `docker network create` command.

As suggested in [this post](https://qiita.com/kojiwell/items), I was trying to do:

```
docker network create \
    --driver bridge \
    --subnet=<WHAT TO SUPPLY HERE?> \
    --gateway=<WHAT TO SUPPLY HERE?> \
    --opt "com.docker.network.bridge.name"="docker1" \
    shared_nw

# Add my host NIC to the bridge
brctl addif docker1 eth1
```

Then start the container as:
`docker run --name myApp --net shared_nw --ip 172.18.0.3 -dt ubuntu`

Somehow it did not work. I will appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction about how to set such a thing up. Grateful!

Answer (score 1):

On your use-case the `ipvlan` docker network could work for you.

using your assumptions about the host ip address and mask, you could create the network like this:

```
docker network create -d ipvlan --subnet=172.18.0.1/16 \
-o ipvlan_mode=l2 my_network
```

Then run your docker container within that network and assign an IP address:

```
docker run --name myApp --net my_network --ip 172.18.0.3 -dt ubuntu
```

Note that any exposed port of that container will be available on the `172.18.0.3` ip address, but any other services on your host will not be reachable with that IP address.

You can find more info on ipvlan at the [official docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/ipvlan)

Answer (score 0):

The [`docker run -p`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) option optionally accepts a bind-address part, which specifies a specific host IP address that will accept inbound connections.  If your host is already configured with the alternate IP address, you can just run

```sh
docker run -p 172.18.0.3:80:8080 ...
```

and `http://172.18.0.3/` (on the default HTTP port 80) will forward to port 8080 in the container.

Docker has a separate internal IP address space for containers, that you can almost totally ignore.  You almost never need the `docker network create --subnet` option and you really never need the `docker run --ip` option.  If you ran `ifconfig` inside this container you'd see a totally different IP address, and that would be fine; the container doesn't know what host ports or IP addresses (if any) it's associated with.

Comment: Thanks David! Unfortunately, I do not want to configure another IP on the host as that would allow the services running on host to become reachable via the second IP too. Basically, I need to keep each OS instance -- regardless of it being on a host or container -- bound to a single IP on the host LAN. I'm also going to check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714891/assign-lan-ip-address-to-docker-container-different-from-hosts-ip-address. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In general it's helpful to think of a Docker container as a wrapper around a process, not "an OS instance".  (It doesn't run system daemons or its own kernel, and from outside Docker space you reach it the same way you reach it the same way you'd reach any other process on the same host.)